# Can I test paypal sandbox with a real credit card?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have tested my paypal sandbox with a test card and it works fine. But my customer tried it with her real credit card, she intentionally put her CVV and expiry date wrong, the sandbox api worked fine then too. She asked me if this is the expected behavior or not.

As far as I know, the sandbox api would have taken the real credit card as test card and didn't mind the cvv and exp date being wrong. Please correct me if I'm wrong, it is the first time i am working on integrating paypal api on my project.

Comment: Please ask questions about the PayPal API used by software developers to process payments, manage invoices, monitor accounts, etc. For user-level support, contact PayPal directly using their site.

[Questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools, or other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Comment: Why not check the documentation, it is pretty clearly explained that cv2s are not checked: https://www.paypal.com/sg/smarthelp/article/where-can-i-find-test-credit-card-numbers-ts2157

Comment: sandbox is for testing transactions right. by asking this question i meant to reconfirm if this behaviour is right or not. If not then there might have been something wrong with my api code. this isn't a user-level support ques as this isn't for the actual payment but testing payment.

Comment: i have checked the documentation already before posting the ques. i know the cvvs are not checked but that is the case when the card is a test card. i wanted to confirm if that is the case too when the card is a real credit card number. nothing is given about the case when a real c.c. number is used.

Answer (score -1):

in a sandbox mode test credit cards don't include a card verification code (CVV), you can use any 3 digit (say 123) as the CVV for Visa, MasterCard, Discover and Diners Club or 1234 as the CVV for American Express.

Date : you can specify any expiration date in the future, using one of the following formats:

```
PayPal Payments Pro – Use format mmyyyy.
PayPal Payflow Pro – Use format mmyy.
```

So, if she(r customer) intentionally put her CVV and expiry date wrong, but format is proper then definitely sandbox has no issue, and definitely this is the expected behavior

Comment: ok. So sandbox takes her real credit card as a test card right. there is no issue with that? thanks for your response.